# Closing Options Menu on orientation change in Android

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

this is my first post here so hello everyone and forgive me any mistakes common for newcomers.

In my actual `Android 4.0` project im using `Options Menu` which is opened by clicking on one of `ActionBar` items. Items of my menu are asynchronously updated so in some cases it opens before  changes has been made and this is proper behaviour for me. As we know, after user changes an orientation of the device, whole activity is recreated (same for its menu). This use case is properly handled in my code - state of `Activity` is saved.

Problem happens when user opens `Options Menu` and changes orientation when menu is still visible - menu gets recreated and shown. I would like to make it not appear after it has been created.

Is it even possible? I assume that i should do something either in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` or in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's always good to start reading the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page since it contains a few hints on how to use the site.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `closeOptionsMenu()` to close your OptionsMenu manually. If you want to open it at any later time, you could call `openOptionsMenu()`.

Answer (score -1):

I can think of a workaround. set a class variable true in onRestoreInstanceState. override  onPrepareOptionsMenu return false if that variable is true and set that variable to false again. It should give you the behavior you want. comment if there's any problem, I'll post the code.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I tried your solution. Problem is fixed but not the way I want. When `onPrepareOptionsMenu` returns false no menu is created - there is no icons on `ActionBar` at all.
What I want to achieve is preventing `OptionsMenu` to be opened after restoring but also I want all `ActionBar` icons still be visible.